# Mathematical writing: When to write definitions in text and when in a definition environment

Tags: soft-question, article-writing

In mathematical writings (in journals), I noticed that sometimes definitions are listed in a paragraph form, while sometimes they are listed in a definition environment 
" \begin{definition}

\end{definition}"
form.

For good mathematical writing, are there any guidelines on when one should put definitions in paragraph form, and when one should put them in an environment? Purely using paragraph form will lead to very wordy long paragraphs, while putting all in environment may lead to a "disjointed" look, where it is one definition after another.

For theorems, lemmas and propositions, it is clear that the environment format will be better, but for definitions I am not so sure.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't like definitions-in-text at all. It makes it harder to go back and find them. I like everything being spelled out as much as possible in theorem style. Some authors are really bad about this and makes it challenging on others for no real reason.

Comment: I agree with @CameronWilliams on the general principle that all definitions and statements that will be referred to later and multiple times should be easy to find.  Whether this is accomplished by typesetting the definition in the definition environment, or making sure the concept being defined is in a short numbered section with an informative title (see Rudin's textbooks), depends on the stylistic preferences.

Comment: You are right about the risk of the "disjointed look", though.  Another way to make a definition easy to find is by having a subject index at the end of the text.  (Furthermore, I like a subject index that refers to a subsection, not to a page.  As a result, I like all the subsections to be short.)  See H. Cartan's "Elementary theory of analytic functions" and V. Arnol'd's "Ordinary differential equations" for different styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it depends on the purpose of the definitions.

If it's to introduce something new then I prefer the `definition` environment (and ideally a non-trivial example of what's being defined), while if it's to refresh the readers's memory on things that are being assumed I'm happier with a (well-written) paragraph.  The more definitions there are (which is more the case with a refresher section) the quicker the `definition` environment format turns into a shopping list.

By way of example (I guess I have to stick to my own guidelines...): a journal paper on metric measure spaces might want to list the definitions of *doubling measure*, *Radon measure*, *length space*, *geodesic space*, and *rectifiability* with a reference to where more detail can be found and these can be neatly summarised in a paragraph or two.  However, if the same paper goes on to define a new measure for these spaces with specific properties that it then studies I would want that definition to have the `definition` environment.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer makes perfect sense!

Comment: I recall a book on finite graphs whose first chapter was a  numbered list of definitions. These were for the general terms that were used often throughout the book.   If a term is "local", for example, only used once in a lemma, it would be better for the reader if its def'n appeared where it is used.